# 100000 users concurrent to buy the same product in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, concurrency, transactions

I am run into trouble.Let me say,There is a product table,The structure is:

```
ProductID   ProductNumber  ProductName   Quantity

   1         A346457577       AAA            2
```

My requirements:

Assume that per user just can buy one.

In my sytem When 100000 users concurrent submit the order at the same time ,the total quantity

is far more than 2.  How to avoid this?  queue? memcache? I have no ideas.Tks!

Comment: That's one huge online store, with 100,000 users buying the same item at the same time... Read up on database transactions.

Comment: What trouble did you run into? What does go wrong? How do you verify a sale, do you check the quantity before subtracting?

Comment: Yes it is a huge online store

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use transactions. Each transaction is ensuring the consistency of the data (quantity >= 0) at the end of the transaction.

Consistency should be checked exclusively, so no two transactions are allowed to modify quantity at the same time.

**OR**

Do what amazon does - accept the order (no commitment), no modifying of the quantity. Next step is - the services try to process the order (transactions run here), and if something goes wrong (exclusive consistency check), send the order denial message to the customer.

This last approach more fits high availability requirements, when the order processing cannot be afforded within each UI request.

**About Transactions**

Database transactions would be one way to implement. e.g. in T-SQL:

```
begin transaction

set @quantity = select Quantity from Products where ProductName = 'AAA'
if @quantity >= @orderedQuantity
begin
    update Products set Quantity = Quantity - @orderedQuantity 
    where ProductName = 'AAA'

    commit transaction
end
else begin
    rallback transaction
end
```

In general, your transaction needs to make sure that it acquires exclusive write lock over the record it's going to update, and commit data after the consistency check. If the consistency check does not pass, roll back.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.what transactions? database transactions? can you give me a example? tks again

Comment: Yes, database transactions would work. I added an example to my answer on how to do it in T-SQL.